# Spaces Not Working While Using Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: android, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

When I type a space into my Android app I am no longer getting any results in my drop down. How can I fix this? I am encoding the input so I am not sure why it is not working...

Before Space:
[image]

After Space:
[image]

I have looked on https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete but I haven't found anything to help me.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

    atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            placesTask = new PlacesTask();
            placesTask.execute(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
        // For storing data from web service 
        String data = "";

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=AIzaSyDcXFSC2I6ZqxQeAbUMFvJKMrA98217H9U";

        String input="";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=(regions)";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        try{
            // Fetching the data from we service
            data = downloadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Creating ParserTask
        parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

        // Setting the adapter
        atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, the input can have (encoded) spaces in it.  What input value(s) are you using when you notice the problem?

Comment: @pushbit Only when I input a space the drop down goes away and I am no longer getting any output.

Comment: @GreekOphion have you find the solution of this question, I have also referred from same tutorial and experiencing same problem

Answer (score 5):

I just experimented with some search results:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=123+43+Sweden&types=%28regions%29&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDcXFSC2I6ZqxQeAbUMFvJKMrA98217H9U

The URL encode may not be properly encoding the space. If you have something like "123+" in the get it should produce valid result as you see above. Instead you need to do a replace to swap spaces for +'s instead.

```
input=input.replace(" ","+");
```

Try that after your URLEncoder to keep the encoding in but remove any risk of the + being encoded.

HTH

Comment: Tried this and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you debug and make sure that the url in your `PlacesTask` looks like input=123+... and debug the URL in `downloadUrl()` and in the `HttpURLConnection` to make sure it keeps the same format?

Comment: Edited my answer to update the encoding. Basically make sure the final URL you send to the `HttpURLConnection` has the input with the address using +'s instead of spaces. If this is the case, try the URL in the browser and see what predictions you get. If it works on the browser and not in the app the `AutoCompleteTextView` may be the problem instead.

Comment: @sturrockad Locatehttps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Sector+24&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDo_9RsCh1Hlw1LgNjEdyf3HPyZ76PE0eY         this is my data but space are still stopping suggestions

Comment: Add  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it's work for me

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try "." instead of space . You should replace space with dot(.) , If its not working You should try "\ " as in ubuntu. May be useful

Answer (score 1):

try by replace this line

```
        input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
```

by

```
        input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fond a solution there is nothing wrong with TextWatcher().

need to use below code 
In below code I didn't override "performFiltering" method I added it and my auto complete text box now working fine.

public class CustomAutoCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

```
public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context) {  
    super(context);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,  
        int defStyle) {  
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
}  

@Override  
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {  
    String filterText = "";  
    super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);  
}  
/** 
* After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing 
* text 
*/  
@Override  
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {  
    super.replaceText(text);  
}
```

}